# stable_sort within a class

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, stable-sort

I have been having an issue with type when using `std::stable_sort`
I keep getting the error:

```
argument of type 'bool (Memory::)(const Mem&, const Mem&)' does not match 'bool (Memory::*)(const Mem&, const Mem&)'
```

I cannot figure out why it is showing up as a pointer...if someone could take a look that would be much appreciated.

Memory.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

#include "Memory.h"
#include "constants.hpp"

Memory::Memory(int _type) {
    fit_type = _type;
    blocks = 1;
    mem[0].address = 0;
    mem[0].size = 2048;
    mem[0].item_id = EMPTY;
}

void Memory::sort_mem_list() {
    // Sort by address
    std::stable_sort(mem.begin(), mem.end(), Memory::compareByAddress );
}

bool Memory::compareByAddress(const Mem &a, const Mem &b) {
    return a.address < b.address;
}
```

And Memory.hpp

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H_
#define MEMORY_H_

#include <vector>
#include "process.h"
#include "constants.hpp"

class Memory {
public:
    Memory(int);
    int add_item(Process pr);
    void remove_item();
    void sort_mem_list();
    void set_fit_type(int);
    void memory_dump();

private:
    bool compareBestFit(const Mem & a, const Mem & b);
    bool compareWorstFit(const Mem & a, const Mem & b);
    bool compareByAddress(const Mem & a, const Mem & b);
    bool compareByProcess(const Mem & a, const Mem & b);

    int fit_type;
    int memory_size;
    int blocks;
    std::vector<Mem> mem;
};

#endif /* MEMORY_H_ */
```

Mem ( currently in constants.hpp )

```
struct Mem {
    int address;
    int size;
    int item_id;

    Mem() {
        address = 0;
        size = 0;
        item_id = EMPTY;
    }
    Mem(int a, int b, int c) {
        address = a;
        size = b;
        item_id = c;
    }


};
```

I am sure it is something fairly simple and I am just messing up the declaration somehow, but I have been stuck on it for a while so a second set of eyes would be most helpful.

Comment: pass a pointer to function by sticking `&` in front

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something foolish

Comment: Compiler was shouting : _you are passing me_ `bool (Memory::)(const Mem&, const Mem&)` but I asked for a pointer _bool (Memory::`*`)(const Mem&, const Mem&)_ -- that was compiler speaking to you ;-)

Comment: Oh damn you're right, I guess that what happens when you stare at something too long

Comment: try to take a walk or distract yourself in some other way, if you see yourself spending too much time with little or no result. _my two cents_

Comment: It looks like you needed a "Rubber Duck" to explain your problem, so you would be able to see for yourself what was the problem

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning on using a member function as the comparator passed to `std::stable_sort()` it needs to be a `static` function.